# Fill Form Data using AJAX with Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to Fill my Form Data with Autocomplete selected Item. My Autocomplete is works fine but i could not figure out how to fill my form data by retrieving the item from Autocomplete text box. Here is my code

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetAutocomplete(string term)
{
    var custo = (from customer in db.tbl_Customers
                 where customer.Name.Contains(term)
                 select new { label = customer.Name, val = customer.customer_ID }).ToList();
    return Json(custo);
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetDetails(string id)
{
    tbl_Customers custodetail = db.tbl_Customers.Single(x => x.customer_ID.ToString() == id);
    return Json(custodetail, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Ajax Function in cshtml View

```
function custoautocomplete()
{
    $(function () {
        $("#Customer_ID").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    async: false,
                    url: '/Orders/GetAutocomplete/',
                    data: "{ 'term': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return item;
                        })),
                        function (item) {
                            $.ajax({
                                cache: false,
                                async: false,
                                type: "POST",
                                url: '/Orders/GetDetails/',
                                data: { "id": data.item.Customer_ID},

                            success: function (data) {
                                $('#Customer_Contact').val(data.Customer_Contact)
                                $("#Billing_Address").val(data.Billing_Address)
                                $("#Shipping_Address").val(data.Shipping_Address)
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: can u please let me know, how. I m new in ajax.

Comment: N.P. I m waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the`.select` event and make you ajax call there to update the DOM based on the selected value. You should also make the changes in the ajax call of the `source` event as noted below

```
$("#Customer_ID").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            // async: false, NEVER do this
            url: '@Url.Action("GetAutocomplete", "Orders")', // don't hard code your url's
            data: { term: request.term }, // change
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", delete
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { 
                        label: item.label, 
                        id: item.id
                    }
                }));
            }
        })
    },select: function(event, ui) {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetDetails", "Orders")',
            data: { id: ui.item.value },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#Customer_Contact').val(data.Customer_Contact)
                $("#Billing_Address").val(data.Billing_Address)
                $("#Shipping_Address").val(data.Shipping_Address)
            }
        });
    }
});
```

As a side note, you do not need `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` in the `GetDetails()` method since its marked `[HtpPost]`. In addition you should be returning an anonymous object (there is no point sending extra data across the wire when you never use it), for example

```
var custodetail = db.tbl_Customers
    .Single(x => x.customer_ID == id) // .ToString() not required - see below
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Customer_Contact = x.Customer_Contact,
        ....
    };
```

and your parameter should be the same as the type of `customer_ID`, for example

```
public JsonResult GetDetails(int id)
```

You also nee to modify the `GetAutocomplete` to

```
var custo = (from customer in db.tbl_Customers
             where customer.Name.Contains(term)
             select new { label = customer.Name, id = customer.customer_ID });
return Json(custo);
```

Comment: Now my rows are adding dynamically and i want to fill row data according to  row index. how would i achieve that?? @Stephen Muecke

Comment: @Zaini, You need to ask a new question with the relevant details.

Comment: Then save it :) - I do not know what problems you having or what code you tried (typically you have a hidden input for that property, and in the `.select` function, you assign the value to that input e.g. `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)` and `select: function(event, ui) { $('#id').val(ui.item.Id);` so its posted back with the rest of your form)

Answer (score 0):

I am very late at this, but I think you don't need to call two different actions. This can be achieved in the first call itself. I have implemented exact same thing for one of my project.

**Edit your controller code to return data at once:**

```
public JsonResult GetAutocomplete(string term)
{
    var custo = (from customer in db.tbl_Customers
                 where customer.Name.Contains(term)
                 select new { label = customer.Name, val = customer.customer_ID, contact = Customer_Contact, billingAddress = Billing_Address}).ToList();
    return Json(custo);
}
```

**Check this ajax code:**

```
    $(function () {
                $('.autofill').autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/Order/GetLocations",
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "JSON",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            data: "{ 'Prefix' : '" + request.term + "', 'Search' :'" + $(this.element).attr('search') + "' }",
                            success: function (data) {
                                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                    return {
                                        lable: item.label,
                                        value: item.val,
                                        contact: item.contact,
                                        billingAddress: item.billingAddress
                                    }
                                }))
                            },
                            error: function (response) {
                                alert(response.responseText);
                            },
                            failure: function (response) {
                                alert(response.responseText);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    select: function (e, i) {
                        var _type = e.target; //get the control that caused the auto complete event  

  $("#Billing_Address").val(data.Billing_Address).val(i.item.billingAddress);
                    },
                    minLength: 3
                });
            })
```