# Pass multiple Id's against multiple values in database

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, sql-insert

I'm working on a task that uses autocomplete textbox items containing names, stores in textbox or in listbox with their associated Id's(hidden) and inserted into the required table (only their related id's). I'm working on mvc 5 application. So far I've achieved to add value in listbox with names but not Id's. And trying to add the listbox values get stored in database. Below is my code.

**Note:-** I'm using partial view to display listbox when the button clicks. The current scenario is that it the listbox overwrites the first value when inserting second value.

**StudentBatch.cs**

```
  public List<string> selectedids { get; set; }
        public List<string> SelectedNames { get; set; }
```

**Create.cshtml**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentName, new { id = "StudentName" })
        <input type="button" value="Add Text" id="addtypevalue" />
        <div id="typevaluelist"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="new" style="display:none;">
    <div class="typevalue">
        <input type="text" name="typevalue" />
        <button type="button" class="delete">Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Students" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#StudentName").autocomplete({
            //autocomplete: {
            //    delay: 0,
            //    minLength: 1,
            source: function (request, response)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Student/CreateStudent",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { Prefix: request.term },
                    success: function(data) {
                        try {
                            response($.map(data,
                                function (item)
                                {
                                    return { label: item.FirstName, value: item.FirstName };
                                }));
                        } catch (err) {
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            messages:
                {
                noResults: "jhh", results: "jhjh"
            }

        });

    });
</script>

   <script>
    $('#addtypevalue').click(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {


                    var selValue = $('#StudentName').val();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetListBox", "Student")',
                        dataType: "html",
                        data: { CourseId: selValue },
                        success: function (data) {
                            $("#partialDiv").html(data);
                        },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert('oops something went wrong');
                }
                });


        });
    });
</script>
```

**GetListBox.cshtml**

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.StudentBatch

@if (ViewBag.Value != null)
{
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedNames, new SelectList(Model.SelectedNames))
}
```

**StudentController.cs**

```
public PartialViewResult GetListBox(string CourseID)
        {
            Context.Student studCont = new Context.Student();
            Models.StudentBatch student = new Models.StudentBatch();
            student.SelectedNames = new List<string>();
            student.SelectedNames.Add(CourseID);
            ViewBag.Value = student;

            return PartialView(student);
        }
```

Comment: Your autocomplete never gets an `ID` value because you ever assign one. All you use is the `FirstName` property.

Comment: In any case you do it using the .select` event of autocomplete, not using the `.click` event of your textbox

Comment: Yes you are right I'm not using ID value, because i dont want to display id as value in autocomplete but want to use it and store it in the database

Comment: You don't need to display it - you just need to return it from the controller method and assign it to a property of the autocomplete items, and then get it in the `.select` event - refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47234514/fill-form-data-using-ajax-with-jquery-autocomplete/47236213#47236213) for a typical example

Comment: And do not clone your input - your generating duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html (and it appears you have ignored all the comments I made on your last question)

Comment: Alright, this time I'm changing my code and implementing listbox instead of multiple textboxes. I'm updating my question again.

Comment: Please see my updated question @StephenMuecke